# Objective C - UICollectionViewListCell Add swipe to delete

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate, nscollectionlayoutsection

Trying to implement "**Swipe to Delete**" API **for UICollectionViewListCell.**

I'm writing in Objective-C
the compiler is not auto-completing the code.
Any reasons? example code?

Swift example:

```
  let listConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)

listConfig.trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationProvider = { [weak self] indexPath in 
  guard let self = self else { return nil }
    
  let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Done!", handler: actionHandler)
  return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])

}
```

Any code example for **Objective C**?

**trying to reach the following result:**

[image]

Comment: No tested, but I guess that something like that https://pastebin.com/X5SYwEVK might do the trick. I didn't do the `[weak self]` because you don't use `self` inside the closure, but to do so, read about `weak self` in Objective-C if you need it.

Comment: This is a repost of your previous question: [Objective C - UICollectionViewListCell swipe to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75200737/objective-c-uicollectionviewlistcell-swipe-to-delete). Instead of reposting you should edit the original as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration * listConfiguration = [[UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration alloc]initWithAppearance:UICollectionLayoutListAppearanceInsetGrouped];
    [listConfiguration setTrailingSwipeActionsConfigurationProvider:^UISwipeActionsConfiguration* (NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        
        UIContextualAction *action = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleNormal title:[NSLocalizedString(@"Delete", nil)capitalizedString] handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {

        }];
        
        return [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:@[action]];
    }];
```